# Show a frame step by step

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have seen people showing one slide progressively by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Could anyone tell me how to realize that in Beamer?

Comment: First have a look at the [documentation](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/) . There you can find the section _Overlays_

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`beamer` provides `\pause` that provides this functionality. You can add that anywhere in the slide and it will "pause" the output there, produce an additional slide for post-pause display.

Additionally, many commands typical to LaTeX have been modified in `beamer` to provide a so-called *overlay specification*. As an example, the following list show each item only on the specified slides:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item<1-> First item
  \item<2> Second item
  \item<3> Last item
\end{enumerate}
```

Here, the overlay specification is contained within `< >`. Slide 1 will contain only the "First item". Slide 2 will contain "First item" and "Second item". Slide 3 will contain "First item" and "Last item". This example, taken from the front page of the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) provides another view on overlay specifications:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{There Is No Largest Prime Number}
  \framesubtitle{The proof uses \textit{reductio ad absurdum}.}
  \begin{theorem}
    There is no largest prime number.
  \end{theorem}
  \begin{proof}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item<1-| alert@1> Suppose $p$ were the largest prime number.
      \item<2-> Let $q$ be the product of the first $p$ numbers.
      \item<3-> Then $q+1$ is not divisible by any of them.
      \item<1-> Thus $q+1$ is also prime and greater than $p$.\qedhere
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{proof}
\end{frame}
```

The display depends on the theme used. Below is the first slide of the above `frame` code from two different themes (left: `default`; right `Frankfurt`):

[image: Same frame, different themes in beamer]

There are many slide overlay specifications possible. Review the package documentation to see the format provided with each command/environment.

Comment: In particular, look at section 9 "Creating Overlays" in the documentation.

Comment: Is there a way to apply this same approach to a slide that has a sequence of full-size images that should appear one after the other, as in a paused sequence but within the same slide?

Answer (score 6):

Using `\pause`before each `\item` in your `itemize` or `enumerate` lists will actually accomplish what you're looking to do. This isn't the most efficient solution, but it certainly gets the job done.

Edit: Ooph. Sorry. Just saw this question was from 2011.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The use of `\pause` is already mentioned in [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26989/106162)