# beamer: how to use \pause with textblock* environment

Tags: beamer, floats, pause

I'd like to show the parts of my slides one after the of the other. I found the `\pause` command, but it doesn't work with my graphics, which are in the `textblock*` environment for being in the position they are supposed to be because that was the only solution I could find.

When  I have a slide with`\pause`, the figures (graphics) appear all before the first `\pause` can "show" them. It feels like they ignore that command.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Try 1}
    \begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(0.8\textwidth,1cm)%specific position, I hope the numbers cannot matter...
        \includegraphics[width=4cm,keepaspectratio]{tryone.eps}
    \end{textblock*}\vfill\pause
\lipsum[1]
\pause
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Pretty nailed it.
Is the solution with`\begin{textblock*}`a good one at all for positioning the graphics?

Comment: Maybe [How to show images step by step in beamer in the same location](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207322/124842) solves your problem. [An other option is [Show a frame step by step](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26989/124842).] Keep always in mind to add always a  [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: It's not what I look for. I'd like the graphics to behave like the text does.

Comment: Cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80495/15925

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instruct `\includegraphics` on which overlays your image should be displayed, e.g. if you want it to act like of there had been a `\pause` before the image, use `<+(1)->`.

And as you have already been told in comments, you don't need `graphicx` in beamer.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
%\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Try 1}
    \begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(0.8\textwidth,1cm)%specific position, I hope the numbers cannot matter...
        \includegraphics<+(1)->[width=4cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
    \end{textblock*}\vfill\pause
\lipsum[1]
\pause
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```